# Space analyticity of solution to heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain, $T>0$, and let $u$ solve, classically:
$$\partial_tu-\Delta u = 0 \text{ on } U\times (0,T) \\ u=0 \text{ at }t=0$$

Can I conclude that $u$ is real analytic in space, for $t>0$? How about the case $t\geq 0$?

I am sorry for the probably easy question for the experts among you but by browsing around I couldn't find, up to now, a reasonable result in this direction. Would you be so kind to point me to a reference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $u=0$ on $\partial U$? Otherwise the solution is just zero.

Comment: Why so? I might impose a non-homogeneous Dirichlet condition at $\partial U \times (0,T)$, say, $u=g$ and $g$ vanishing at $t=0$, and the solution would not be zero

@TrevorNorton

Comment: That's true. I was supposing homogenous BCs. Do you know what the BCs are in this case? Are you supposing smooth Dirichlet BCS?

Comment: @TrevorNorton I am assuming $u=g$ with $g$ be a smooth function in a neighbourhood of $\partial U \times (0,T)$ (because I can't define spatial smoothness by just requiring $g$ to live on $\partial U$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 62 of "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans it says [image: Evans]

The book [M] is "Partial Differential Equations" by Mikhailov.