# Spatial analyticity for solutions of linear parabolic PDEs

Tags: analyticity, parabolic-pde

I believe that the following result is true, but am having a hard time finding a suitable reference to convince myself:

*Suppose $X:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is analytic. If the smooth function $u:(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ solves the parabolic equation*

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta u+ X\cdot \nabla u,$$
*then for each $t>0$, the mapping $x\mapsto u(t,x)$ is analytic.*

The elliptic version of this result is frequently cited as "well-known" in the literature, and in fact, there is this result for elliptic non-linear systems as well:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372830.

The parabolic result is for the regular heat equation ($X=0$) is discussed here: [Space analyticity of solution to heat equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468262/space-analyticity-of-solution-to-heat-equation). However, the proof it refers to appears to lean quite heavily on an explicit expression for the heat kernel/fundamental solution, which might not be available if $X\neq 0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the result you’re looking for is given in:

*Classes of solutions of linear systems of partial differential equations of parabolic type* by Avner Friedman.

Duke Math. J. 24 (3), 433-442, (September 1957) DOI: 10.1215/S0012-7094-57-02450-X

Comment: Thanks! That does the job quite nicely I believe.